# My chromecast isn't appearing in the receiver list callback

Tags: sender, google-cast, chromecast

I'm testing my chromecast with pjjanak's `chromecast-hello-world` app located on github [here](https://github.com/pjjanak/chromecast-hello-world).

He adds a listener to the `message` event, which is effectively checking that the content API is getting injected.

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    if (event.source === window && event.data &&
        event.data.source === 'CastApi' &&
        event.data.event === 'Hello') {
        console.log('message event');
        initializeApi();
    }
});
```

`message event` is getting correctly logged to the console, so I'm sure the chrome app whitelisting is set up correctly.

I also have the following:

```
initializeApi = function() {
    if (!cast_api) {
        cast_api = new cast.Api();
        cast_api.addReceiverListener('my_app_id_is_here', onReceiverList);
        console.log('initializeApi');
    }
};

onReceiverList = function(list) {
    console.log('receiverlist:' + list);
    //snipped other stuff from here...
}
```

The problem is, that the addReceiverListener is being called, but the receiver list is always empty. The console just logs: `receiverlist:`

My Chomecast appears to be in developer mode, as I can access the developer tools through port 9222. However, I didn't have the "Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates" box ticked previously (I've ticked it now, and performed a few reboots/resets to no avail).

I'm quite stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has now started working.

It could be a result of one of three things that I did:

- Waiting ~1hr after checking the 'serial number to google' box.
- Launching some other content on the device (I watched a video on YouTube)
- Disabling the cache on the device through the chrome developer developer tools at `[device-ip:9222]`

Comment: The first one was the reason

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and I've tried just about everything. It's been several hours since I checked the box, and I've rebooted the device. 0.o

Comment: @JacobEnsor Have you had any luck.  I have the same issue.  It has been days since I checked the box, and it is still not working.